# PHP sent email subject - Hotmail/Outlook show £ as Â£

Tags: php, email

When I send an email containing £ using PHP mail it appears in outlook/hotmail as Â£. In Gmail/thunderbird it's fine.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: What character encoding are you using for this text?

Comment: That's a UTF issue - you're embedding UTF-8 characters in a document that's using some OTHER character set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, the client doesn't know what encoding is used to encode the subject. Whatever your application sets in `Content-Type` header only applies to the body of the email, not the headers.

Usually this affects the following headers:

- Subject
- From
- To

In order to use different encodings your internationalized header lines should be MIME-encoded (as of RFC 2047), using one of the two methods: base64 (B) or modified quoted-printable (Q). The encoded subject usually looks like this:

```
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Pr=FCfung_f=FCr?= Entwerfen von einer MIME kopfzeile
```

This may look difficult, but there is one very handy helper function in PHP which does all the magic:

- [iconv_mime_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-encode.php) - Composes a MIME header field

Alternatively you may look into discussion under:

- [quoted_printable_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php) - Convert a 8 bit string to a quoted-printable string

Before using `quoted_printable_encode()` directly you neet to take into account that long lines need to be split at certain length and spaces need to be replaced with underscore "_".

Answer (score 2):

Just today I fixed a similar subject encoding issue by using [phpmailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) instead of php's builtin `mail`:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = "utf8";
$mail->Subject = $mail->EncodeHeader("You won £10000000!");
....
$retval = $mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use the `mb_convert_encoding()` function

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8"); //AUTO DETECT AND CONVERT
mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "latin1"); //MANUAL SET - CHANGE latin1 TO CURRENT ENCODING
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UTF-8 encoding in your email.

Answer (score 0):

this had results for my

```
<?php $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?="; ?>
```